# Issues building WPF related to video driver VS2012

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, nvidia

Recently, I got a strange problem in Visual Studio 2012 building WPF projects.

When I have Video Drivers installed, it takes ages to load the XAML Viewer and the WPF Application itself, when starting Debug. This is also for the exe file.

When the Video driver is uninstalled (using Basic MS driver) everything runs just fine.

I allready tried different driver versions (win 7 Professinal 64bit) for my NVIDIA 8700m GT with no success.

Anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS 2012 use WPF as its UI. The WPF for VS 2012 is WPF 4.0, and it needs DirectX 9.0c support with Pixel Shader 3.0 support.
But VS 2012 requires at least Windows 7 SP1, and full support of WDM 1.1 is recommended.
Your graphic card, NVidia 8700m GT supports DirectX 10 partially, but this means it support DirectX 9.0c as well.

You should download the latest driver from NVidia; the latest driver for Windows 7 32bit and Windows 8 32 bit is 306.97.

The link is: http://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/306.97/306.97-notebook-win8-win7-winvista-32bit-international-whql.exe

Comment: Forgot to mention its 64bit. Downloading the driver. Will check tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: No success? Do you computer have a hybrid of Intel GMA and NVidia, or just a dedicated NVidia?

Comment: Nothing, its an old Asus G2SG. 5 Years old. 
Im trying to reinstall DirectX. Maybe that will help.

Comment: @CSharpie wait.. which version of windows do you have? if you have windows 7 sp1, you don't have to reinstall DirectX.

Comment: Well i got a new machine and problems are gone. I guess the GPU / Video memory was done, since it started to crash frequently a few days later with havy fragments on screen.